# Download file from server response with url as .json file

Tags: javascript, json, download

I have a web service that returns a file to requesting browser as url with .json extension.  Ex:

https://somesite/rest/directories/output/_ags_SessionFile_f46fd461-b437-11e7-9dc1-005056bd201b.json

The intent is to simply navigate this url and invoke the "SaveAs" or simply save the .json file to the downloads directory.

This works in most instances, however on computers that do NOT have the .json file type association to IE (found in ControlPanel-->default programs) then the file is not downloaded or user prompted with SaveAs option and a new browser window is opened with the contents of the .json file displayed in the page.

I'm a bit unsure how to search for such a thing, even this post may be inadequate as I simply have not run into this issue ever.

```html
   function downloadFile(results, messages) {
                    
                    //set a var of the complete url address that is returned from the GP service request
                    var urlOfFile = results[0].value.url;
                    
                    //get the div from the html of the widget
                    link = document.getElementById('downloadSession');

                    link.setAttribute('href', urlOfFile);
                    link.click();

                }
```

```
<div> 
    <a id="downloadSession" href="" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the HTML5 `download` attribute to the `<a>` tag should work for you

[Anchor Tag doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

> download HTML5
>
> This attribute instructs browsers to download a URL instead of navigating to it, so the user will be prompted to save it as a local file

The docs also note some gotchas like it will only work for same-origin URLs and a few others so its worth a read.

Unfortunately the `download` attribute is not supported in Internet Explorer so for the download to work properly you will have to add `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` headers on the response from the server

they should look something like:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"filename.json\"
```

Comment: I don't really understand how to implement the example on that page.  canvas?  Thank you for your input!

Comment: I am suggesting to replace `<a id="downloadSession" href="" target="_blank"></a>` with `<a id="downloadSession" href="" target="_blank" download></a>`

Comment: ah, I see.  Thank you will try!

Comment: Thanks again.  It (in IE) has the same result: when expecting the download process, instead a new tab opens and simply displays the content of the file.  Change html to <a id="downloadSession" href="" target="_blank" download></a>

Comment: ah I see. Apparently the `download` attribute is not supported in IE. You will have to do some more work to get IE to download.  I will update my answer

Comment: Ok thank you!  Where do I add the changes to the header?  Unfortunately, the html is a "widget" contained within the larger application's index.html page.  Just not sure where to place it.

Comment: So that would go in the server code that is hosting the .json file. If you don't have control of that server to add those response headers then I am not sure you can get what you are looking for :(

Comment: Ok.  I am the owner of that service, so perhaps I can implement.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add header:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.json');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $json;
```

Comment: Add it where?  The .js code is contained within a widget that has it's own .html within the larger index.html container.